# iOS - UILabel inside tableview cell

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm very much new to iphone development and strucked at a point. Actually my need is I'm displaying some results in a `UITableView` and I'm displaying then `UILables` of `UITableView's` cell..
How can I make the `UILabel's` to adjust the content according to the text. Actually text is not static .It may be changing at run time.So I need to set dynamic size to a UILabel .Ans secondly suppose if the text is `null` then it should not show any space and immediately the next `UILabel` should start .How can I make it possible ?
Here is my code..

```
self.tableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,150,320,800) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
            self.tableView.delegate=self;
            self.tableView.dataSource=self;
            self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
            [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(currentHtmlElement==@"3")
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";

        UITableViewCell* cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
        }
        NSMutableDictionary *d = (NSMutableDictionary *) [arr2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.accessoryType= UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
       UILabel  *name1= [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 320, 40)];
        name1.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        [name1 setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
        [name1 setText:[d valueForKey:@"Name"]];
        name1.tag = 111;
        [cell addSubview:name1];
        [name1 release];

        UILabel *codetype=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 45, 320,15)];
        codetype .font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];        
        [codetype setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
        [codetype  setText:[d valueForKey:@"Code"]];
        codetype.tag=112;
        [cell addSubview:codetype];
        [codetype  release];    

        UILabel *id=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 68, 320,10)];
        id .font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:12];        
        [id setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
        [id  setText:[d valueForKey:@"ID"]];
        id.tag=113;
        [cell id ];
        [id  release]; 

        UILabel *address=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 85, 320,10)];
        address .font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:12];        
        [address setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
        [address  setText:[d valueForKey:@"address"]];
        line2.tag=114;
        [cell addSubview: address];
        [address  release]; 

        UILabel *city = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 105, 320, 10)];
        city .font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:12];        
        [city  setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
        [city  setText:[d valueForKey:@"City"]];
        city.tag=115;
        [cell addSubview:city ];
        [city  release];
}
```

Here I have set all the UILabels to static size.But what I need is dynamic size.and suppose if the address label is null then it should not show any space and next label i.e city should start immediately next after id ..How is it possible?

Comment: according to me...your text is overlapping in your label..

Comment: why are you not using reusable cell..?

Comment: What I actually need is for the first Label I would give fixed  dimensions.and from the second label,label should set automatically its dimensions(y axis and height) according to the prevoius label's content.and if suppose , if value of one label is null then that label should disappear and immediately next label should start..How can I do it ?

Comment: This is in no way related to Xcode.

Comment: You should only use english on stackoverflow

Comment: But tumne us post par koi response nai diya to how can i help you.. time waste karo nd ek bhi like nai..:(

Comment: @Rajneesh071.Actually after that I was away from work and so couldn't reply..I m implementing ur code of prevoius question.But as u have said I dont know exact size of labels,tableview bcoz I need to set them dynamically..

Comment: its ok...but when you are dynamically changing label then just save the label height..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this task in my code.... you can use this code and do changes according to your code....and let me know if you get any problem.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dicNotification =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary: [myNotification objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    //code to get notification text height
    NSString *text = [dicNotification  objectForKey:@"message"];
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(175, 100.0f);
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return size.height;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        //label for message
        UILabel *lblMsg = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        lblMsg.tag = 12;
        lblMsg.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [lblMsg setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12]];
        [lblMsg setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        [cell addSubview:lblMsg];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *dicNotification =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary: [myNotification objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    //get the message height set frame height to imageView(BubbleMid & Top) & labelMSG
    NSString *txt = [dicNotification  objectForKey:@"message"];
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(175, 2000.0f);
    CGSize size = [txt sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    //set frame height to labelMsg
    UILabel *lblMsg = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:12];
    lblMsg.frame = CGRectMake(15,25, 175, size.height);
    [lblMsg setNumberOfLines:size.height/16];

    //set labelMsg text
    lblMsg.text = [dicNotification  objectForKey:@"message"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get ur logic clearly.Should I write it for all UILabels if there are many in heightForRowAtIndexPath..?and is there  a specific reason that size.height/16?

Comment: could u please explain me a little bit

Comment: initially forgot height for row...just concentrate in making label... first i created label with font size 12... then have some text in "txt".. my label is of 175 width so i am setting 175 for constraint. now after getting size i am setting label height... and now you setNumberOfLines = 100; its depend on you, using size.height/16 i am getting that how much lines in label is needed,.. i know you are thinking that why not size.height/12 -> so the reason is -> text is in between label..so 2 pixel upper padding and 2 pixel at bottom.. 12+4 =16. you will get my logic if you implement it..:)

Comment: I have many labels in a cell .In ur code ,if I dont know the number of lines for  a label  then how can I know the y-origin of another label below it?I mean where should the second label start ?

Comment: fine can u please tell me abt return size.height + 35; in heightForRowAtIndexPath ?is it adjusting row height according to content in it?

Comment: actually i have only one label in my row height so i did with one label..and +35 is used because i need 35 pixel more size then label size... you can do it for all label.

Answer (score 0):

you can make `UILable` adjust content with bellow code

```
CGSize sizeToMakeLabel = [name1.text sizeWithFont: name1.font]; 
name1.frame = CGRectMake(name1.frame.origin.x, name1.frame.origin.y, 
sizeToMakeLabel.width, sizeToMakeLabel.height);
```

and here set second lable like bellow..

**UPDATE**

```
     if([[d valueForKey:@"address"] isEquelToString:@""]){
          UILabel *city=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, idLable.frame.origin.y + id.frame.size.height+10 , 320,15)];
          city .font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:12];        
          [city  setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
          [city  setText:[d valueForKey:@"City"]];
          city.tag=115;
          [cell addSubview:city ];
          CGSize sizeToMakeLabel = [city.text sizeWithFont: city.font]; 
          city.frame = CGRectMake(city.frame.origin.x, city.frame.origin.y, 
sizeToMakeLabel.width, sizeToMakeLabel.height); 
        }
      else{
          UILabel * address =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, idLable.frame.origin.y + id.frame.size.height+10 , 320,15)];
address .font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:12];        
          [address setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
          [address  setText:[d valueForKey:@"address"]];
          line2.tag=114;
          [cell addSubview: address];
          CGSize sizeToMakeLabel = [address.text sizeWithFont: address.font]; 
          address.frame = CGRectMake(address.frame.origin.x, address.frame.origin.y, 
sizeToMakeLabel.width, sizeToMakeLabel.height); 
        }
```

and so on for every label..

follow this logic for whole label

i hope this help you...

Comment: No actually what I need is if suppose address is null then it is showing empty space after id and then next city value starts .But what I need is it should not show any empty space if address is null and immediately city should start...How can I do it ?

Comment: What I actually need is for the first Label I would give fixed dimensions.and from the second label,label should set automatically its dimensions(y axis and height) according to the prevoius label's content.and if suppose , if value of one label is null then that label should disappear and immediately next label should start..How can I do it ?

Comment: @Esha see the Updated answer here i post the code for only one label so put this condition for another label dear i just give the idea for this solution i hope you understand it.. :)

Comment: but in the code u gave u r setting some static height to UILabel.I need to set its height dynamically according to the content.If suppose I have some large data in one label then it doesnot show the whole data and next label appears.so I need dynamic height of label ...How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you must use heightForRowAtIndexPath. The problem is that it is called prior to cellForRowAtIndexPath, therefore the text is not in the component and you can not simply adjust the component size to the text. So, what you do is calculate the text size using a sizeWithFont.

In case of **normal/standard text**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //here you get your text string
    NSString* theText =  ... ; 

    //then calculate the size. systemFontOfSize depends on your font size
    //yourLabelWidth must be known and usually depends on scree size or if the tableview has an index
    CGSize textSize = [theText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(yourLabelWidth, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    return textSize.height;
}
```

In the case of **attributed text**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //here you get your text string
    NSAttributedString* theText =  ...;

    //then calculate the size.
    //yourLabelWidth must be known and usually depends on scree size or if the tableview has an index
    CGRect rectSize = [theText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(yourLabelWidth, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:NULL];

return rectSize.size.height;

    return textSize.height;
}
```

Comment: What I actually need is for the first Label I would give fixed dimensions.and from the second label,label should set automatically its dimensions(y axis and height) according to the prevoius label's content.and if suppose , if value of one label is null then that label should disappear and immediately next label should start..How can I do it ?

Comment: @Esha As I showed you, you have to calculate all your sizes dynamically. The process I gave is for one cell. You have to loop through your label list, defining eachlabel height. Note that the height that is returned by heightForRowAtIndex is the height of the cell which must match the sum of all your label (+ padding eventually). I assume you are using storyboard, you should create a custom cell with all your labels and size them and place them in the heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @Esha This link should help you understand what I mean. http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1 and go to "Designing Our Own Prototype Cells". Personally I don't use tag. But what is presented is the idea. You already create the custom cell. You don't create the labels at runtime, you just size them and position them at runtime and this is done in the heightForRowAtIndex.

Comment: @Esha Also doing so will allow you to "reuse" cells by simply placing label and sizing labels and no RE creating them which will help much in performance.

Comment: I created tableView programatically.Can u please tell me how?Where should I start?

Comment: yes because I do have some labels and buttons also in that view after which tableview appears

Comment: You said you where "new" to iPhone. Personally I came from other languages and also from desktop programming. When I learned iOS programming I had to re-think my way of thinking things [think different :-)] to match apple iOS philosophy and way of doing. In your case, check if you are really required to do it dynamically or  if you can do it the other way.